# Can QGIS be coaxed into exporting text as text in an SVG?

Tags: qgis, svg

Having resolved my [squished projection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167181/why-would-an-svg-output-from-cartodb-look-squished-when-the-map-doesnt/) I'm now facing the fact that QGIS exports all my labels as vectors, which means I can't take the map over to Inkscape and fine tune the fonts without retyping them all. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sooooo,

Under Layer Properties > Labels, there's a little button at the top right, hover and it reads "Automated Placement Engine".

One of the options in that dialog is "Draw text as outlines (recommended)" and that does, indeed, export text labels instead of outlines.

So glad I managed to find it.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same problem, and on a mac I would choose 'print' instead of exporting as svg or pdf directly, and in the print dialog I would choose 'save as pdf'. This exported the text as text and not vectors.

Comment: Sadly, the PDF I wind up with has nothing that inkscape recognizes as text either.

Comment: Are you on a Mac or pc @Amanda ?

Comment: I'm running Linux.

Comment: Can't help you there, unfortunately.